# How can I disable 'Personalize your web experience' MS Edge prompt for Selenium tests

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

Starting with MS Edge version 113.0.1774.50 my Selenium tests (written on c#) started to fail, because of appearing 'Personalize your web experience' prompt.
['Personalize your web experience' prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su9jC.png)
The issue is reproduced if tests use new user profile. This dialog can appear randomly, but more often, when I am navigating to the link with my application and trying to login into it.
Note: the issue was not reproduced on MS Edge 113.0.1774.42 and earlier, and it's not reproduced on MS Edge Beta 114.

I want to turn off this dialog. Tried to turn of different Edge policies via register using PowerShell scripts

1. disable PersonalizationReportingEnabled policy - did everything according to the [article](https://winaero.com/how-to-disable-personalize-your-web-experience-prompt-in-microsoft-edge/), setting is disabled, but dialog is still appearing;
2. disable DefaultBrowserSettingsCampaignEnabled policy - [it was added in MS Edge 113](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-relnote-stable-channel#version-1130177450-may-18-2023), so I thought, that it can be related.
3. disable following policies (separately): HideFirstRunExperience, SoftLandingEnabled, SubscribedContent-310093Enabled, ShowRecommendationsEnabled
4. tried to disable properties, which were added in MS Edge 113 (all together).Taken form this article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies: DiscoverPageContextEnabled, EnforceLocalAnchorConstraintsEnabled, EnhanceSecurityMode, ReadAloudEnabled, RestorePdfView, TabServicesEnabled

Comment: Did you add HideFirstRunExperience key to HKEY_CURRENT_USER or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE?

Comment: I have the same issue. Great write-up of the problem and what's been tried. I'm temporarily running Selenium tests with an existing user profile.

Answer (score 8):

You can run Edge in Guest Mode to avoid the `Personalize your web experience` prompt.

Here's how to set that option for Python users:

```py
options.add_argument("--guest")
```

Comment: Oh my simple but works perfectly. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 4):

It seems that I've found solution for the problem:

It was found, that 'Personalize your web experience' prompt is not displayed, if 'Personalization & advertising' option is turned ON (open MS Edge, go to the 'Settings' -> 'Privacy, search, and services' -> 'Personalization & advertising' section and turn on this option)
[image]

If you need to do it for Selenium tests via code, do the following:

```
  var options = new EdgeChromiumOptions();
  options.AddUserProfilePreference("user_experience_metrics", new
  {
     personalization_data_consent_enabled = true
  });
```

Another options is go to the 'Edge Profile' folder -> 'Default' -> 'Preferences' and set this option manually to true
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried run the browser in Inprivate mode? In order to achieve this you can add this option as argument.

```
private static readonly ThreadLocal<IWebDriver> driver = new();
edgeOptions.AddArgument("-inprivate");

new WebDriverManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new EdgeConfig());
driver.Value = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
```

Comment: In incognito I don't see such prompt, but unfortunately, I can't run tests in Incognito.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully replicated this issue, but I'm afraid that currently there's no such group policy to control this behavior. If you would like to see such a group policy introduced in the future releases, you can submit feedback by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in the browser.

As a workaround, you may need to **specify a profile** for automation test to avoid   this prompt.

However, here's an interesting behavior I've found. I hope it will be helpful to you: **if the current page is refreshed or redirected, the prompt will no longer exist.**

Answer (score 0):

You will need disable both of these settings.  I just got this info from MS and it is working for me.

Group Policy (ADMX) info
GP unique name: ShowRecommendationsEnabled
GP name: Allow recommendations and promotional notifications from Microsoft Edge
or GP name: Allow feature recommendations and browser assistance notifications from Microsoft Edge
GP path (Mandatory): Administrative Templates/Microsoft Edge/
GP path (Recommended): N/A
GP ADMX file name: MSEdge.admx

Windows Registry Settings
Path (Mandatory): SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge
Path (Recommended): N/A
Value Name: ShowRecommendationsEnabled
Value Type: REG_DWORD

And

Group Policy (ADMX) info
GP unique name: PersonalizationReportingEnabled
GP name: Allow personalization of ads, Microsoft Edge, search, news and other Microsoft services by sending browsing history, favorites and collections, usage and other browsing data to Microsoft
GP path (Mandatory): Administrative Templates/Microsoft Edge/
GP path (Recommended): N/A
GP ADMX file name: MSEdge.admx

Windows Registry Settings
Path (Mandatory): SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge
Path (Recommended): N/A
Value Name: PersonalizationReportingEnabled
Value Type: REG_DWORD

Answer (score 0):

```
Java Code:
Here is the code logic to handle the notification
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();                        
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");      
Map<String, Object> prefs = new LinkedHashMap<>();          
prefs.put("user_experience_metrics.personalization_data_consent_enabled", Boolean.valueOf(true));           
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);          
driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```